# How can i know the length of a cursor on PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can i know the length of a cursor?

I need to do something like that:

```
For i in (select * from table)
loop
    x := i.length
end loop;
```

I mean, i need to take the length.

Is this posible on PL/SQL?
Is there some way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why?  What is the problem that you're trying to solve?  It sometimes makes sense to do something if a query returns 0 rows or to do something on the first row or every nth row none of which need to know how many rows will eventually be returned.  The `count(*)` analytic function would work (at a cost) except if the query returns 0 rows in which case the loop won't iterate at all.  Not sure if that is a concern or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to ask the cursor itself to tell you it's length.  Oracle does not know the length until after it has fetched all the rows.

It'd be a performance hit, but you can do in the cursor's SQL, like this:

```
For i in (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by null) cursor_length from table t)
loop
    x := i.cursor_length;
end loop;
```